# Why does Gatsby no longer recognize components in site-directory?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gatsby

I had a perfectly working gatsby site when I wanted to add functionality to the `gatsby-node.js` file and did `npm install slug`. The new code did not work so I reverted it, but I can not get it working again. I get the default 404 page when doing `gatsby develop`, and the message:

> There's not a page yet at /

though I have not changed the file `src/pages/index.js`.
I clearly have a component in the `index.js` file, but Gatsby does not recognize it. 
I have tried to remove `node_modules`, `package-lock.js` and `.cache`, and then do `npm install` but no luck. 
I even tried cloning my repo from when it was working, but I get the same error. 
I tried creating a new gatsby site which works properly, so I cannot figure out what is going on.

Why is this happening? Let me know if I should post more code from my project.

Thanks.

Comment: What changes did you introcude to `gatsby-node.js`? It's always a good idea to include all related code snippets, or even recreate your project in an online playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually worked it out.
I have been using Auth0 in my app to handle authentication. I do not know the exact reason of the sudden error, but some of the code in `gatsby-node.js` looked like this:

```
// Implement the Gatsby API “onCreatePage”. This is
// called after every page is created.
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
  // only on the client.
  if (page.path.match(/^\//)) {
    page.matchPath = "//*"

    // Update the page.
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

By changing it to this:

```
// Implement the Gatsby API “onCreatePage”. This is
// called after every page is created.
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
  // only on the client.
  if (page.path.match(/^\/account/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/account/*"

    // Update the page.
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

the components loaded again.